# Store number in array when user press button to generate random number in android

Tags: android

i want to store number in array one by one ...when user press button it will generate number in Text field ..i want to store that number in array

Comment: what is the problem? What have you tried?

Comment: i dnt know what to do....i generate number store in variable from there i store it in array like this array[i]=number then i++;

Comment: what is your actual problem?

Comment: when use press button a random number appear in textfield i want to store this number in array and also when the user press button again then store next random number in array at next index

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a simple problem...I am writing this but I will hope you will first try and then ask a question from next time:
For this problem u just need to use the function Math.random() in your onClickListner() of your button. Now place this no in textview by using the function setText().
For eg if ur textview name is tv then use tv.setText(no) where no=Math.random()

Comment: i know how to generate random number    Random rand=new Random();
                num1=rand.nextInt(max-min+1)+min;
                num2=rand.nextInt(max-min-1)+min;
                txtvw1.setText(""+ num1);
                txtvw2.setText("" + num2);

Comment: problem is that when user press button to generate number how to store it in array at the same time and also then next time  when user again press button again store it in array at next index

Comment: Make a static integer variable(for index) now whenever the button is clicked place the value in array at this index and then  increment this index. Next time when user will click the index value will be what u need only

Comment: ok if user generate 10 number then how to print the array in txtxfield with 10 number in it

Comment: Use for loop and add these numbers to a string...like this. String all = new String(""+a[0]); for(int I=1;I<index; I++) all.append(a[I]); once this loop is over add this string to textview. Got it?

Answer (score 0):

Something like that?

```
findViewById(R.id.ButtonRandomNumber).setOnClickListener(mRandomListener);
TextView randomNumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.randomNumber);


private OnClickListener mRandomListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Random rand = new Random();
            array[array.length + 1] = rand;
            randomNumber.setText(String.format(rand));
        }
    };
```

Make the array a global variable and that should more or less work. Was that what you wanted to know?